# implement 2 flavors of Equals method for a class in Java

Tags: java

```
public class Foo{
    private final int A;
    private final int B;
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        //type check omitted
        return A==o.A && B==o.B;
    }

}
```

I want to have another `.equals()` method like this

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
    return A==o.A;
}
```

The Foo object is first created with A,B field, then I want to send them off to a `Set<E>` that used the 2nd equals() method to **only compares field A**.

I know I can create new objects that only have A field, but overhead would be big. Any advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using composition, you could create a `FooWrapper` class that provides a custom implementation of `equals` and add that to the set instead:

```
public class FooWrapper {
    public final Foo foo; //constructor omitted

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
         //type check omitted here too
         return foo.A == other.foo.A;
    }

    //hashCode omitted, but you need that too
}
```

Unfortunately with the Java Collections API there is no way to tell a collection to use a custom `equals` computation other than the method above or subclassing and overriding `equals()`.

### Edit:

It strikes me that you might instead be able to make use of a `Map<Integer, Foo>` instead, using `foo.A` as the key and `foo` as the value (and thus restricting it to unique values of `A`).  I couldn't tell you whether that's suitable without more context though.

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one implementation of equals per `Object` as it's overriding the inherited method from `java.lang.Object`.  I think you need to decide on what equality means for `Foo` - is A the only significant field; if so just use that.  Your alternative is to wrap `Foo` and provide a custom `equals` method for the `WrappedFoo` Object.  You can then store `WrappedFoo` in the `Set`.

From a design perspective it sounds like there should be two Objects here - one which is a value class for A and one which is a value class for B.  You can use composition if you need a single Object to represent A and B.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a matcher framework for this:

The base interface is Matcher (similar to Comparable):
http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/util/Matcher.html

MatchableObject is a class, which applies a matching strategy to an Object: 
http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/util/MatchableObject.html

Matchers is a utility class to wrap/ unwrap MatchableObjects:
http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/util/Matchers.html

The library is Open Source. Maybe you find it useful.

Homepage:

http://www.softsmithy.org

Download:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/softsmithy/files/softsmithy/

Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupid>org.softsmithy.lib</groupid>  
    <artifactid>lib-core</artifactid>  
    <version>0.1</version>  
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the alternate equals method is just for this particular set, I'd suggested using TreeSet (or another SortedSet) instead of HashSet so that you can use the `TreeSet(Comparator)` constructor.